# Mysql Many to many relationship, display results in one row

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

Please help me, I tried but couldn't find the right answer. I have 5 tables `users, profile, questions, question_responses and profile_responses`. Users have to provide answers for questions like

1. region (Ontario, British Columbia, etc),
2. ethnicity(White, Chinese, South Asian, etc)
3. genre(Food, Health, Fashion, etc)
4. country(Canada, UK, USA).

profile_responses table has many to many relationships with profile, responses, and profile_responses. The following are the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  'email' varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  'password' varchar(300) NOT NULL,
   'name' varchar(300) NOT NULL,
   'user_type' varchar(10) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `password`, `name`, `user_type`) VALUES 
(8, 'test1@gmail.com', '', 'Test Name1', 'Influencers'),
(14, 'test1@gmail.com', '', 'Test Name2', 'Influencers'),
(15, 'test1@gmail.com', '', 'Test Name3', 'Influencers');



CREATE TABLE `profile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `instagram_handle` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
   `comments` text NOT NULL
);
 
INSERT INTO `profile` (`id`, `user_id`, `name`, `instagram_handle`,`comments`) VALUES
(1, 8, 'Test Name1', 'testhandle1', 'Test Comments'),
(10, 14, 'Test Name2', 'testhandle2', 'Test Comments'),
(12, 15, 'Test Name3 ', 'testhandle3', 'Test Comments');



questions
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL
);
 
INSERT INTO `questions` (`id`, `text`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 'country', 1),
(2, 'ethnicity', 1),
(3, 'region', 1),
(4, 'genre', 1);



question_responses
CREATE TABLE `question_responses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `abbr` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO `question_responses` (`id`, `question_id`, `text`, `abbr`, `active`, `sort_order`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'USA', 'US', 1, 0),
(2, 1, 'UK', 'UK', 1, 0),
(3, 1, 'Canada', 'CA', 1, 0),
(7, 2, 'South Asian', 'SA', 1, 0),
(8, 2, 'Chinese', 'CH', 1, 0),
(9, 2, 'White', 'W', 1, 0),
(13, 4, 'Lifestyle', 'Lifestyle', 1, 0),
(14, 4, 'Fashion', 'Fashion', 1, 0),
(15, 4, 'Food', 'Food', 1, 0),
(16, 4, 'Health & Fitness', 'Health', 1, 0),
(18, 3, 'Britich Columbia', 'BC', 1, 6),
(19, 3, 'Ontario', 'ON', 1, 1),
(20, 3, 'Alberta', 'AB', 1, 9),
(23, 3, 'Taxes', 'TX', 1, 52),
(24, 3, 'California', 'CA', 1, 15);


profile_responses
CREATE TABLE `profile_responses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `response_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES profile(user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
  FOREIGN KEY (response_id) REFERENCES question_responses(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO `profile_responses` (`id`, `user_id`, `response_id`) VALUES 
(1, 8, 3),
(2, 8, 18),
(3, 8, 15),
(4, 8, 9),
(5, 14, 1),
(6, 14, 23),
(7, 14, 16),
(8, 14, 9),
(9, 15, 3),
(10, 15, 19),
(11, 15, 14),
(12, 15, 7);
```

I am trying to display each user responses in one row like following

```
Name            Region      Ethnicity           Genre                   Country
Test Name1      BC              White           Food                    Canada
Test Name2      Taxes           White           Health & Fitness        USA
Test Name3      Ontario         South Asian     Fashion                 Canada
```

For the solution, I created two queries. First, I figure out how many users have answered the questions. As responses vary so N (having count) is based on the set of response. This query is working fine.

```
SELECT pro.user_id
FROM profile_responses as pr
INNER JOIN profile as pro ON pro.user_id = pr.user_id
WHERE pr.response_id IN (3,18,15,23,16,19,14,7) 
GROUP BY pro.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pr.response_id) >= N
```

For displaying results I tried the following which is working but if I have 10 questions then I have to write ten combinations? Please help me I'm not an expert.

```
select us1.id, us1.email, up1.name, up1.instagram_handle, qr.abbr as region, qr1.abbr as ethnicity, up1.followers,qr2.abbr as genre, qr3.abbr as country, up1.comments
FROM users as us1
LEFT JOIN profile as up1 ON up1.user_id = us1.id

LEFT JOIN profile_responses usrep ON up1.user_id = usrep.user_id 
JOIN question_responses qr ON usrep.response_id = qr.id AND qr.question_id = 3
JOIN questions qs ON qs.id = qr.question_id

LEFT JOIN profile_responses usrep1 ON up1.user_id = usrep1.user_id 
JOIN question_responses qr1 ON usrep1.response_id = qr1.id AND qr1.question_id = 2
JOIN questions qs1 ON qs1.id = qr1.question_id

LEFT JOIN profile_responses usrep2 ON up1.user_id = usrep2.user_id 
JOIN question_responses qr2 ON usrep2.response_id = qr2.id AND qr2.question_id = 4
JOIN questions qs2 ON qs2.id = qr2.question_id

LEFT JOIN profile_responses usrep3 ON up1.user_id = usrep3.user_id 
JOIN question_responses qr3 ON usrep3.response_id = qr3.id AND qr3.question_id = 1
JOIN questions qs3 ON qs3.id = qr3.question_id

WHERE us1.user_type="Influencers" AND us1.id IN (8,14,15)
GROUP BY us1.id
```

Comment: Can you dump your data here? i can't test it, add more details, about your data

Comment: Please add some sample data as INSERT INTO and show desired output strictly for this data, not "like following", with demonstrating rows collapse.

Comment: Please check i have added sample data.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: So no one can help me.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me?